# UIButton background image maker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I find it too difficult to make a UIButton look good, and setting background images works but I am not the best at making gradients and suck. Does anyone know of a button maker that's designed for iPhone and iPad buttons? Or does anyone have any tips?

Comment: What don't you like about the way a UIButton looks by default? Can you show a screenshot of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: The UIButton with rounded rect style is the most useful style for UIButton. However, it is always white and there is no way to change it unless you draw the background image by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Adobe Photoshop to create buttons.  Here's a great reference with many different tutorials on creating buttons.  (If you don't have Photoshop, try Gimp, an open source free alternative)

http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/40-best-photoshop-tutorials-for-creating-buttons-and-badges/

Answer (score 3):

You can try Adobe Photoshop, but if you want to do it programmatically you can try this site which is a tutorial on applying your button with Core Animation.

Here it is: [Fun With UIButtons and Core Animation Layers](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/)